# GET can't be processed. The connection is not yet established and the offline queue is deactivated

Tags: javascript, npm, redis, node-redis

Getting the following exception in production, even though I have a retry strategy of 500ms and a setTimeout of 1s wrapping the setAsync and getAsync functions. Not sure what's going wrong here.

```
AbortError:
   at handle_offline_command (at handle_offline_command (/usr/src/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:779:15)at handle_offline_command (/usr/src/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:779:15): /usr/src/app/node_modules/redis/index.jsat handle_offline_command (/usr/src/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:779:15): 779)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're firing a command before the connection is established, and the [`enableOfflineQueue`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis#offline-queue) is set to `false`.

You can solve it in two ways:

1. enable the offline queue, and the commands will get queued and send once the a connection is establish.
2. make sure the connection is ready before firing commands (either by listening to the `connect` event, or with the callback/promise of the `.connect` function. You can read more about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis#auto-reconnect)).